Converting a HEX color value to RGB in JavaScript
I have this code:
let hexInt = parseInt(hex, 16);

let r = (hexInt >> 16) & 255;
let g = (hexInt >> 8) & 255;
let b = hexInt & 255;

I know that a HEX digit requires 4 bits to specify its value. So, 6 HEX digits mean 24 bits where each color component gets 8 bits.
F0 is 11110000
0F is 00001111

F0 in decimal is 240
0F in decimal is 15

What I can't understand is that parseInt(hex, 16) converts our HEX string to a decimal value and they don't have such straight forward conversion.
84 in binary is 1010100
48 in binary is 110000

With decimal numbers, the number of bits changes based on the magnitude of the number.
This did not happen with the hexadecimal number.
The number hexInt in my code is now a decimal number. It magnitude will depend on the HEX value. Therefore, the number of bytes used to represent it will depend on the HEX value.
Therefore, we can't always do 16 and 8 bit right shift to isolate color components.
Why does the above code work then?
What am I missing?
Thanks.

Short version:
We can use 16 and 8 bit shifting to isolate components because a hex color by design always uses 8 bits per component. The magnitude of component does not matter. If you want Red and its value is 00 then you must shift 8 "zeros" by 16 places (to the position of Blue) before extracting the Red value.
Example:
color   : #00F7A5
comp    : RR = 00, GG = F7, BB = A5
Mask    : & FF0000 (mask to keep first two hex digits from RRGGBB )
Shift   :  >> 0  , >> 8   , >> 16 (makes new output of 0000RR)
Mask    : & 0000FF (or just) & FF (mask to keep last two hex digits from 0000RR )

Simplified version for same result is: (myColorInt >> 16 ) & 0xFF).
Longer Answer...
Regarding Hex notation:

"I know that a HEX digit requires 4 bits to specify its value. So, 6 HEX digits mean 24 bits where each color component gets 8 bits."

A hex digit requires at minimum 1 bit to specify its value (even if that value is 0).
A hex color ALWAYS requires 8 bits per component (for either: Red, Green or Blue).
A color component like 0F seems to use only 4 bits but it is really 8 bits, just that the front 4 are set to zero, but they still count towards the 8 bit total of this component.
There is an 8-bit count because each component is binned into one R/G/B slot. A slot initially holds 8 zeroes.
Why 6 hex digits for 24 bits?
In a hex color, you have 3 values (for RGB), which are each made of 2 hex digits. This is because each R/G/B value is 8 bits. Basically they're each a byte value. A single byte is 8 bits long but itself can be divided into two halves of 4 bits where each unit is called a nibble. A byte is 2 hex digits to represent its two nibbles for 8 bits.
A nibble (4 bits) is not counted. Only a full byte (as one 8-bits or two 4-bit nibbles) is the component's value.
Regarding Bit-shifting with >> and Masking with & operators:

What I can't understand is that parseInt(hex, 16) converts our HEX
string to a decimal value and they don't have such straight forward
conversion.
84 in binary is 1010100
48 in binary is 110000

With decimal numbers, the number of bits changes based on the
magnitude of the number.
The [decimal number's] magnitude will depend on the HEX value.
Therefore, the number of bytes bits used to represent it will depend on the
HEX value.
Therefore, we can't always do 16 and 8 bit right shift to isolate
color components.
let r = (hexInt >> 16) & 255;
let g = (hexInt >> 8) & 255;
let b = hexInt & 255;

Why does the above code work then?

Your logic is correct for cases where any random amount of bits used.
However RGB notation is a system (or standard?) where each component is binned into an 8-bit slot. It becomes the rule that the bit-shifting must happen to extract any Red, Green or Blue value.
Therefore in a hex color, we must always use 16 or 8 bit-shifts to isolate the R/G/B components.
Consider the 24-bit integer 0xRRGGBB which is really 3 bytes [RR] [GG] [BB].
byte offset :   02 01 00
component   :   RR GG BB
bit-pos     :   16 08 00 //# how far from zero (to isolate)
Mask & FF00 :   00 FF 00 //# mask [r,g,b] as [-,g,-] using "& 0x00FF00"
Result      :   00 GG 00 //# result output of mask (notice is now "GG00")
Result >> 8 :   00 00 GG //# shift bits torward zero ( 0000[00GG00] --> 00[0000GG]00 )
Result & FF :         GG //# mask is "& 0x0000FF" for isolated Green value eg: 230

